# Eclipse and FFTW

Tags: eclipse, gcc, include, g++, fftw

I have some troubles in making a FFTW (and FFTW++) static project in Eclipse in my MacOS Lion. Have someone already made it?

I've made a separate folder for the include files, but it seems like it can't find them despite I have set the path correctly. I've also replaced in all the c-files the includes with the path `<subdirectory/include_file>` setting in the Directories section of my project settings
`${workspace_loc:/FFTW3/include}`.

I don't know if it's relevant but as I wrote my code, using another IDE and typing the commands from bash, I realized that some mp options were needed, so I've updated my version of gcc from 4.2.1 (that is the basic Xcode version for MacOS) to 4.7. I've compiled the FFTW++ example and it worked, compiling it with `g++ -fopenmp`. I have used macports to install the new version of gcc and I have used one of its options (`sudo port select --set gcc mp-gcc47`) to set it as gcc default command, in place of the 4.2 version, so I can type and compile from bash.

Now I have seen that Eclipse uses the version 4.2.1. Does somebody know how to change it into the 4.7 version? Do you think that this could solve the problem or it's a cause for my problem?

Comment: If you just build and install FFTW in the standard locations (/usr/local/include, /usr/local/lib) then you shouldn't need to do anything special for your project build, as these locations are searched for includes/libraries by gcc by default.

Comment: Yes I know, but I need it as an internal Eclipse project, not as an external library. This is because I'm not working alone and I it's required to not force everyone to have these libraries installed on their laptop.

Comment: Oh dear - that's going to be nasty then.

Comment: That's what I feared :(
There's any other help from the web, I passed the last 3 days googleing, but there's nothing useful..

Comment: I'd go for the holistic solution - insist that everyone on the team installs FFTW. If that doesn't work then create a script to do this automatically and incorporate the script into your Eclipse project.

Comment: Yep, I would agree but unfortunately I don't know if this is what the boss wants!
Is this really an impossible thing to achieve?

Comment: No - I'm sure it's doable - it just seems like a very painful solution. Try presenting a convincing case to "the boss" that if you're going to be dependent on a third party library for a project then it's not unreasonable for developers in the team to have to install that library.